# Create a widget to use shortcode?

Tags: widgets, shortcode

I have a plugin (Social Warfare) that I love.  But, there's no widget available.  What is involved in creating a widget so that I can use the shortcode that seems to work fine on the pages and posts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find more information in the [Widgets API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a Shortcode using the built-in text widget. To get the widget to process Shortcodes, add the following filter in your theme's `functions.php`:

```
add_filter( 'widget_text', 'do_shortcode' );
```

This will result in widget text being passed thru `do_shortcode`, which will render any Shortcodes embedded in the text. Just note that this may not work for all Shortcodes, depending on what it actually does and if it needs a specific context to work properly.

Comment: Worked like a champ !!